# Apache PdfBox, How to check the available blank space on a page

Tags: java, pdfbox

In Apache PdfBox 1.8.0 Java Lib, How to know that the page is 100% full and new page should be created now.

Comment: With pdfbox it's *you* who does the layout, so *you* decide whether a page is full or yet another bit of content can be squeezed into it. This if course means that you have to always know where you are putting content on the current page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this was answered here before, but I can't find it. There's also a tool that does this, look at TextToPDF in the source code download (tools subproject).